# How to use the log4j2 wrapper API

Tags: java, wrapper, log4j2

I do have some trouble understanding the log4j2 wrapper usage.

If you follow this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-138?attachmentOrder=asc) you will find attached an example using the AbstractLoggerWrapper. I just copied the following peace of code.

```
public class Log4j2Logger extends AbstractLogger 
{

    private static final String FQCN = AbstractLogger.class.getName();
    private AbstractLoggerWrapper logImpl;

    public Log4j2Logger(String name, String prefix, String logId, String instanceId)
    {
        super(name, prefix, logId, instanceId);
        final AbstractLogger logger = (AbstractLogger) LogManager.getLogger(name);
        this.logImpl = new AbstractLoggerWrapper(logger, name);
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public void log(String message, LogLevel level)
    {
        logImpl.log(null, FQCN, toImplLevel(level), new SimpleMessage(createMessage(message)), null);
    }

    ....
}
```

I don't understand the reason for subclassing AbstractLogger and intern using the AbstractLoggerWrapper. I actually could just remove the extend from the Log4j2Logger and encapsulate the AbstractLoggerWrapper. Do you see any reason of doing it like in the code snipped above?

Is there any way to subclass the AbstractLogger (like [preferred](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLogger.html)) and just use it without the wrapper? And create it like a strategy pattern? e.g.,

```
LogManager.getLogger( class.getName(), Log4j2Logger.class )
```

Maybe this is what they tried to explain in the [extending section](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) and I don't understand it, yet. Somebody any idea how to do it?

Sincerely
Christian

Update: I missed to say, the reason why I am using the wrapper is because of an existing projekt with log4j (1.2) with a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [AbstractLoggerWrapper](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLoggerWrapper.html):

> Wrapper class that exposes the protected AbstractLogger methods to
>   support wrapped loggers.

You will see a clear indication as to why it is done the way Apache does it.  If you instead decide to ignore the contract of the interface and go your own way, you are essentially saying

> "I don't care how the library does things, I know better"

As such, you are taking on a great deal of risk, instead of using the general solution that has been provided.  I sincerely doubt that you have such an esoteric environment that the library could would be insufficient.

To recap, follow the contract laid out by the library documentation.

Comment: I am not at all knowing it better, thats the reason I am asking how to use it proper. :)